# $A,B$ matrices , prove $Bv = \Lambda v$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A,B$ are $n \times n$ matrices  and $AB = BA$

Also, there is an eigenvalue $\Lambda$ in $A$ which its geometric complexity is $1$.

Also there is $ v \ne 0 $ that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

Prove that $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$

Comment: It would be good if you shared some thoughts on the problem.

Comment: It might be beneficial to note that this is part of what is known as the commuting operator theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $1$ of $A$ and $v \neq 0$ is an associated eigenvector. If $Bv = 0$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ associated to the  eigenvalue $0$. If $Bv \neq 0$, note that
$$\lambda Bv = B(\lambda v) = BAv= A(Bv).$$
This shows that $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since the [geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenspace_and_spectrum) of $\lambda$ is $1$, the eigenspace $V_\lambda$ is of dimension $1$ and thus we must have $Bv = \alpha v$ for some coefficient $\alpha$ (because $Bv \in V_\lambda = \text{span} \{v\}$). This shows that $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$ associated to the eigenvalue $\alpha$.

Comment: Nice answer. But I still didnt get thr last part sorted out.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Is it more clear now?